# RxJava filtering empty list and using firstOrDefault

Tags: java, android, list, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to filter a list which might or might not be empty (or the item is not in the list). inboxData is filled by another observable:

```
private BehaviorSubject<InboxResponse> inboxData = BehaviorSubject.create();

public Observable<Item> getInboxItem(String id) {
    return inboxData
        .flatMap(response -> Observable.from(response.getData()))
        .filter(item -> item.getId().equals(id))
        .firstOrDefault(null);
}
```

In this case if response.getData() is empty firstOrDefault never runs. But why? It clearly says that it gives you back the default value if the preceeding observable emits nothing.

Comment: @Kiskae's answer is correct. Also, please note that once you do call `onCompleted` on a `BehaviorSubject`, all subsequent observers will only receive `onCompleted`, never any data. I'm not sure a `Subject` is what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`firstOrDefault` emits the default if the stream **completes** without any items being passed through the observable. For your stream to complete the `BehaviorSubject` would need to signal completion. Since there is no indication that happens it would never realize it needs to send the default.

The solution is to move the `filter` and `firstOrDefault` to the inside of the `flatMap` so the end of the list provided by `getData` ends up completing the inner stream.

Note that if you're using RxJava2 as your tags suggest, `null` can never be an item in the stream, so passing it as default would cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Observable<Item> getInboxItem(String id) {
    return inboxData
        .flatMap(response -> Observable.from(response.getData()))
```

At this point, response.getData() returns null, right?

```
        .filter(item -> item.getId().equals(id))
```

That means that `item` here is null. So `item.getId()` throws a `NullPointerException`. An error like that is immediately passed to the subscriber's onError handler. The `firstOrDefault` method will not even be called anymore, because the stream is immediately terminated.

```
        .firstOrDefault(null);
}
```

Comment: No, response.getData() is an empty list if there is no data

Comment: I think its something about behavioursubject never calling oncomplete so the firstOrDefault cannot call the default part.